# Separating internal and external constructors with the same set of parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a type that takes a value, checks it against the type's parameters, and from that point on allows the value to carry around that check as an invariant. The type also has a number of operations associated with it that create new values of that type. All those operations are defined so that the check is not needed. There is no way once the user's value is in the type to ever have an invalid value of that type.

What I need is two constructors: one internal and one external. The external constructor should perform the check, while the internal constructor should not. They otherwise have the same parameters, the only difference is the check, which is the main issue. The check is avoided for performance reasons. Below is a mocked up example.

```
#include <stdexcept>

template <int limit>
class ClippedValue;

template <int limit>
void check(ClippedValue<limit> v) {
    if (std::abs(v.value) > limit) {
        make_user_solve_P_eq_NP();
        throw std::range_error("Given value exceeds available range");
    }
}

template <int limit>
class ClippedValue {
public:  // external constructor
    constexpr ClippedValue(int a) : value(a) { check(*this); }
private:  // internal constructor
    constexpr ClippedValue(int a) : value(a) {}
public:  // members
    const int value;
public:  // friends
    template <int A, int B>
    friend constexpr ClippedValue<A + B> operator+ (ClippedValue<A> a, ClippedValue<B> b);
}

template <int A, int B>
constexpr ClippedValue<A + B> operator+ (ClippedValue<A> a, ClippedValue<B> b) {
    return a.value + b.value;
}
```

The above doesn't compile, the two constructors are identical.

Comment: Having two identical functions do different things is a logical error. You may either want to add additional dummy parameters or use factory functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The above doesn't compile, the two constructors are identical.

Indeed. So differentiate them.

```
enum class unchecked_t {};
constexpr ClippedValue(unchecked_t, int a) : value(a) {}
```

The standard library itself [makes use](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_place) of this paradigm often. It differentiates the overloads, and since `unchecked_t` and its kind can be subject to access control themselves, allows for finer grained accessibility specification, such as with the key-pass idiom.

Comment: Won't you have to explicitly call the types constructor in that case? Which would require typing the same info in the return type again or using a decltype statement? Or is there a way to return (unchecked_t, value)?

Comment: @ktb - From the friend function? It's as easy as `return {unchecked_t{}, a.value + b.value};` - Uniform initialization not sucking in this case.

Comment: @ktb - No wait. I missed the fact the friend is not defined inline. You need to qualify it `ClippedValue<A + B>::unchecked_t{}`

Comment: should that matter? It's still a friend and has access to unchecked_t?

Comment: @ktb - It has access, of course. But access is checked after name lookup. And name lookup for an inline friend works like it does for member functions. But not for an out of class definition, there you need to qualify like with any free function.

Answer (score 2):

As you already found out, you cannot have two constructors with the same interface.

You can add a dummy argument to the second constructor to differentiate it from the first one.

```
template <int limit>
class ClippedValue
{
   public:

      // external constructor
      constexpr ClippedValue(int a) : value(a) { check(*this); }

   private:

      // A type that can be used only internally and by friends of the class.
      struct internal {};

      // internal constructor. An overload.
      // Use another argument, of type internal.
      constexpr ClippedValue(int a, internal) : value(a) {}

      ...
};
```